# IntelliJ reporting code duplicates that aren't?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is reporting me code duplication warnings, even though I don't think it is an actual duplicate. I can't find anything on google about it so I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

For example:

```
private static float[] getMatrix() {
    switch (matrixMode) {
        case PROJECTION:
            return projectionMatrix;
        case VIEW:
            return viewMatrix;
        case MODEL:
            return modelMatrix;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown matrix mode " + matrixMode);
    }
}

private static Stack<float[]> getStack() {
    switch (matrixMode) {
        case PROJECTION:
            return projectionStack;
        case VIEW:
            return viewStack;
        case MODEL:
            return modelStack;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown matrix mode " + matrixMode);
    }
}
```

This is reported as a code duplicate and I can't see why.
Well, it certainly does look similar, but in no way is it a duplicate.

The usage is also quite different.
I use it to remove actual code duplication in every method, that uses matrices based on the matrix mode like for example:

```
public static void push() {
    switch (matrixMode) {
        case PROJECTION:
            projectionStack.push(projectionMatrix.clone());
            break;
        case VIEW:
            viewStack.push(viewMatrix.clone());
            break;
        case MODEL:
            modelStack.push(modelMatrix.clone());
            break;
    }
}

public static void pop() {
    switch (matrixMode) {
        case PROJECTION:
            projectionMatrix = projectionStack.pop();
            break;
        case VIEW:
            viewMatrix = viewStack.pop();
            break;
        case MODEL:
            modelMatrix = modelStack.pop();
            break;
    }
}
```

Code like this can now be nicely replaced with:

```
public static void push() {
    getStack().push(getMatrix().clone());
}

public static void pop() {
    // setMatrix() also is a helper method of the same style, but does not produce a duplicate warning
    setMatrix(getStack().pop());
}
```

And since I'm kind of ripping of OpenGL (even though OpenGL maybe has it's reasons to do it this way, while I'm just doing it because OpenGL is), it means, that there are a lot of methods that become a lot shorter with the introduction of the two getMatrix() and getStack() (and setMatrix()), removing a lot of actual code duplicates, that IntelliJ does not report as such.

I can't see how to generalize two methods with different return types.
So how is my programming bad, and what can I do? Or is IntelliJ being dumb?

I think the code duplicate feature is really nice, so I don't want to suppress warnings, but it seems to get it wrong sometimes.

Comment: Well, you have the same switch-case in both methods. What if you want to add or delete a case? You have to maintain the code at two or even more different places. If your example actually reflects your production code, this is rather a design issue ... which in the end leads to duplicate code. If you want to stick with it, just ignore or suppress the warnings. They are supposed to help and guide you, and not a strict rule.

Comment: I agree with  @NumLock . The thing that seems worth "more thought" is the fact that you are using **static** all over the place. That smells more like a real issue.

Comment: @NumLock What are design alternatives? Before this I had for a short period of time methods for every stack, like popView(), popModel(). It didn't seem a good idea aswell.

Comment: @GhostCat What are design alternatives? There will always only be one window I draw to, so only one stack for matrices. Letting the Stage always carry a final "stack" pointer, or making the Class a singleton doesn't seem to add much, except the calls to getInstance(). I testet those variants and to me it looks cleaner to just have it static. Is static a bad thing? If it is bad design what should I do differently?

Comment: **static** simply has some severe drawbacks - it creates tight coupling in your code; and writing unit tests gets **harder** - see for example what I just wrong one another question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702680/static-array-of-the-object-the-array-is-created-in-is-this-good-or-bad/39702859#39702859 ... what I am saying is: balancing is required. Maybe **static** is a good solution for you, but in general: just be careful about using it. It has its place; but far too often, it is used in the wrong places.