# Static Array of the object the array is created in. Is this good or bad?

Tags: java, arrays, static

As you can see, I've created (instantiated?) a static array of Corner objects in the object Corner. Is this good form? I want all the Corner object to have access to all the other Corner objects.

```
package Main;

public class Corner {

private String biome;

private static Corner[][] corners;

private float elevation, moisture, heat;

private boolean isRiver, isLake;

private int x, y;

public void createArray(int width, int height) {

    corners = new Corner[width][height];

}

public String getBiome() { return biome; }

public void setBiome(String biome) {
    this.biome = biome;
}

public float getElevation() { return elevation; }

public void setElevation(float elevation) {
    this.elevation = elevation;
}

public float getMoisture() {
    return moisture;
}

public void setMoisture(float moisture) {
    this.moisture = moisture;
}

public float getHeat() { return heat; }

public void setHeat(float heat) { this.heat = heat; }

public boolean isRiver() {

    return false;
}

public boolean isLake() {

    return false;
}

public static Corner[][] getCorners() {
    return corners;
}
}
```

There are no more details to add.

Comment: as a sidenote, a non static initializer for the array as `createArray(int,int)` doesn´t seem to make sense here. On another note if you want to keep track of all `Corner` instances you should also include a `static createCorner` method which also manages your `corners` array and which should be the only way to create `Corner` instances.

Answer (score 2):

If the amount of `Corner`s changes you need to create a new bigger array and copy all the `Corner`s from the old array to the new bigger one.  This should indicate to you that you might want to ave a different data structure than an array. One that can grow like a `List` or a `Set`.

In general, a `Corner` should not need to know of other `Corner`s. A different type should manage all the `Corner`s and handle dependencies between them.

You did not wrote **why** 'I want all the `Corner` object to have access to all the other Corner objects' so I cannot recommend how this managing type could look like.

Comment: The amount of corners never changes. The corners are part of a procedurally generated map with a mesh structure where I have a number of squares made up of 4 triangles each (drawn between 5 vertices, 4 corners and 1 center). I need the corners to get information such as elevation from surrounding corners in order to further generate various things such as rivers.  

Thanks for answering!

Why can't I get line break to work?

Comment: Thanks. That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, taking in not what Kevin has said, you should change

```
public void createArray(int, int);
```

to

```
public static void createArray(int, int);
```

I do not understand the need to have a two-dimensional array for accessing other Corner objects.

Also array is not a good structure type for dynamic allocation. List is better alternative and in this case List. So you should implement it as -

You should create a list as -

```
private static List<Corner>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, **static** is an **abnormality** in good OO design. You only use it if there are very good reasons to do so.

Your example doesn't look like such a case. You see, you are mixing up things that don't belong together. A "corner" is simply that a "corner". It doesn't know about other "corners".

In the model that you are actually creating, you have some "enclosing" thing that deals with corners in plural. That enclosing thing could have some `List<Corner>` field that is used to track all Corner objects belonging to the enclosing entity.

**static** often looks like an easy, convenient way to solve such problems. But in reality, you are just creating a lot of problems by implementing something like this. It works initially, but it breaks as soon you try to enhance your program.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this good form?

No.

There are two reasons:-

**Reason 1 :-** **Single responsibility principle**. Every object should be responsible about its concern . So its not the concern of corner object to maintain the list of other corner object.  Maintaining corner object can go under some util class method or singleton object maintaining the corner cache(which will be easy to test also)

**Reason 2 :-**
**unit testing.** Say you want to write unit test for static method you won't be able to do it easily until and unless you provide any third party lib that provides static mocking like jmockit,